# Debugging system crashes with kdump (20.04)

Tags: kernel, crash

My laptop (Dell XPS 7390, i7-10710U, 16 GB RAM, 512 GB SSD) has been frequently and seemingly randomly freezing so badly that I have to force reboot. I am trying to debug with kdump, since hardware tests haven't turned up any issues. But whenever I manually trigger a kernel panic (via `echo "c" > /proc/sysrq-trigger`), I don't get any output in /var/crash. The system just freezes and has to be force powered-off (the magic SysRq keys don't do anything).
The output of `kdump-config show` is

```
USE_KDUMP:        1
KDUMP_SYSCTL:     kernel.panic_on_oops=1
KDUMP_COREDIR:    /var/crash
crashkernel addr: 0x
   /var/lib/kdump/vmlinuz: symbolic link to /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic
kdump initrd: 
   /var/lib/kdump/initrd.img: symbolic link to /var/lib/kdump/initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic
current state:    ready to kdump

kexec command:
  /sbin/kexec -p --command-line="BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic root=UUID=ed8d53ef-c788-452b-abf5-4e3a7086891f ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7 reset_devices systemd.unit=kdump-tools-dump.service nr_cpus=1 irqpoll nousb ata_piix.prefer_ms_hyperv=0" --initrd=/var/lib/kdump/initrd.img /var/lib/kdump/vmlinuz
```

My `/etc/sysctl.conf` file includes

```
kernel.unknown_nmi_panic=1
kernel.core_pattern = /var/crash/core.%t.%p
kernel.panic=10
```

In `/etc/default/grub.d/kdump-tools.cfg` I have

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT crashkernel=512M-:512M"
```

Any ideas as to what is configured incorrectly, or another way I could debug my random system freezes?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
kdump-config test
```

and increasing `crashkernel` size, though `512M` should be sufficient.

Update `/etc/default/grub.d/kdump-tools.cfg`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT crashkernel=1024M-:768M"
```

and run

```
update-grub
```

finally try invoking panic:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq && echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

and check logs in `/var/crash/`.